# HTML anchor not working on page load

Tags: html, anchor

When I want to refer to some part of my webpage with anchors : "http://example.com/index.html#section_11" it's not going there.

However, once the page has completely loaded and then I go to address bar, highlight this URL and press enter, it works!

```
<div class="ui-paddingbox dotted_bg" id="section_11">
some text
</div>
```

Comment: As far as I know this only works if you are currently on this page and pressing the link, but with jQuery you should be able to achive the same.

Comment: @AlexG No, that's not true. Check this :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._8_%28Sibelius%29#References

Comment: Hmm alright thanks. Tried it, seems to work just fine, maybe you've set the wrong id/target or have disabled the function via javascript.

Comment: I get the same problem, though not for all anchors. It's very strange, and I can't work out the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Anchors only go to  tag, i think. Try this:

```
  <div class="ui-paddingbox dotted_bg">
    <a name="section_11" />
    some text
  </div>
```

And make sure that the element won't added after loading (e.g. with a jquery call)

Comment: No. It works with span on Wikipedia :  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._8_%28Sibelius%29#References

Comment: Yep, your correct. First  don't believed it but the W3C say it's ok (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3 (BTW: they also used a <a> tag :-) ) )

Comment: You can't self-close an `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<a href="#section_11">link</a>
```